Getting tile PNG from PostGIS raster table
I am using PostGIS to save my raster data. I have loaded my TIFF file to the raster table using the following command:
raster2pgsql -e -l 2,3 -I -C -M -F -Y -t 256x256 tw.tif terrain_2d | psql -d db_dev

I split the input raster into tiles of 256x256 pixels. The pixel size is 23 meters. Now I want to serve my map. I need a PostgreSQL function to return PNG, with parameters z, x, y. The function should be like:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_terrain_2d_tile(
    p_raster_type VARCHAR(32),
    z INTEGER,
    x INTEGER,
    y INTEGER
) RETURNS TABLE(tile_png BYTEA) AS $$ BEGIN
RETURN QUERY

Note that, this function should combine all small tiles (256*256) and generate the exact PNG image defined by z, x, y.
